# Sql code current user id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't know why this code doesn't work. Can someone please help me? I don't know so much about sql codes but please help, its written In php because I want my users to enter the page with that file.

This is the sql code

```
 <?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Password");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

$id = $_SESSION['id'] //from your login session

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ally='3' WHERE id='{$id}'");
 ?>
```

This code are supposed to take the id the user that's logged in on the page and send an sql code to the database. When I try to enter the file on a page, ig just get this error

```
Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Folder\htdocs\include\file.php on line 16
```

Comment: what is actually written in line 16 of your file.php?

Comment: Add a semicolon in second line and Remove braces in the query around '$id' then try.

Answer (score 2):

> missing semicolon in   this line $id = $_SESSION['id']

```
<?php
    $verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Password");
    mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

    $id = $_SESSION['id']; //from your login session

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ally='3' WHERE id='{$id}'");
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after

```
$id = $_SESSION['id']**;** //from your login session
```

Answer (score 1):

Add semicolon please.

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may help

when using session start with

```
session_start();
```

and the missing semicolon

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```